# How to deal with a duplicate key from Faker in Ruby

Tags: ruby, httparty

How do I loop if Faker generates an existing name for the name field?

The name field is the primary key in this table. When it finds a duplicate name it will generate until it finds a different name.

```
class Crud
  include HTTParty
  base_uri 'http://dummy.restapiexample.com/api/v1'

  def create 
    nome    = Faker::Name.first_name
    salario = Faker::Number.decimal(l_digits: 4, r_digits: 2)
    idade   = Faker::Number.number(digits: 2)
    #note, you should pass body as JSON string
    body = { name: nome, salary: salario, age: idade }.to_json

    headers = {
      'Accept' => 'application/vnd.tasksmanager.v2',
      'Content-Type' => 'application/json'
    }

    self.class.post('/create', body: body, headers: headers) 
  end

  def retrieve(id)
    self.class.get("/employee/#{ id }")
  end 
end

> client = Crud.new 
> response = client.create
> id = JSON.parse(response)['id']
> client.retrieve(id)
```

Comment: You should just add `format :json` in the class body and HTTParty will take care of both encoding the body as json and setting the content type.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Faker::Name.unique.first_name` should always return a unique name per test run. The caveat is that if you generate a large number it might run out of unique values and raise an error.

You also must clear your database between test runs, or it could generate collisions.

https://github.com/faker-ruby/faker#ensuring-unique-values

Comment: Hi Scott, I can't clean the base because this base is public and I have no control http://dummy.restapiexample.com/ over it!.  Wonderful the help you provided me !. provided ..  Thank you, Thank you..

Answer (score 3):

Depending on your Faker version, you can use [`unique`](https://github.com/faker-ruby/faker#ensuring-unique-values) to ensure unique values:

```
nome = Faker::Name.unique.first_name
```

Answer (score 1):

In a factory sometimes you run out of `unique` values in which case you can use a `sequence`:

```rb
sequence(:field) { |n| "#{Faker::Job.field} (#{n})" }
```